# Fuel in oil, #3 injector code, and won't start now

Tags: ford, fuel-system, escape

I have a 2007 Ford Escape XLT 3.0.  I'm having trouble with it jerking and using a lot of fuel. The codes showed #3 injector.  I've changed the #3 3 times, as well as coils, plugs, PCM, and now exhaust manifold gasket. After driving it, my oil light is now on, as well as my battery light. It won't start, and there's a gas smell in my oil.

Comment: Fuel pressure drop test? Is the injector stuck open? Short to ground on the control wire? Injector pulse width in line with others?

Comment: Also, welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!